# Teradata 15.1 SQL Assistant - Query is invalid if starting with comment

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I was testing the code of my colleague and wrote somments for each statement like this:

```
/*Creating the list of IDs*/
Select ID from table1
```

Everything worked fine until I saved the Query, closed the session and then started the new one with the same Query.
Now if there is a comment, it results with the error "Query is invalid".
If I delete the comment and write the new one on the same place - it works! LOL
WTF is that?!

thx

Comment: Try to upgrade to a later SQL Assistant release, this is a known bug :)

Comment: At least _you_ can remove the comment.  I'm using 16.10.0.2, and even if I paste a query into Notepad without any comments or extraneous characters, then move it into SQL Assistant, I still get "Query is invalid".  My colleague retyped her giant query (instead of copy/paste) and said it works.  I refuse to do this.